# Could Python3 script (requests) used to get data from a website seem 'suspicious'?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, python-requests

Might be a silly question... I want to use a python script to get some data from a website every 10 or 20min.

I'm using:

```
requests.get("http://somewebsite.php")
data = response.text
```

to get the data, and the rest is basically extraction of values from the string etc.

I would like to loop it and make a new request to the website every 10 or 20min to get data.

Assuming I'm running this script for few hours:

- Would it look suspicious to the owner of the website?
- Would it in any way 'hurt' the website or is it just equivalent to refreshing the website in the browser?

I just don't want someone, somewhere think something malicious is happening when I'm just playing around learning python. The data is not even important, I just want to see if the script that I wrote works. I just figured I might ask here before running it.

Thanks for any replies in advance.

Comment: How should we know what the website owners are thinking? How could we POSSIBLY know what they've got for monitoring capabilities on their end? In the broader sense, why do you need to use a "real" website? It's trivial to set up your own webserver and abuse it as much as you want.

Comment: These questions often come up and I always ask the same thing: Do you own the website? Do you have an agreement with the website owner? Websites are people's property and sometimes (often?) connected with their livelihood. Do not make random requests (especially unusual ones) unless you know what you're doing and have an agreement. If  they have a ToS, follow it. If they have an API, use it. If you get banned or blocked, **do not try to work around it**.

Comment: First off - good on you for even asking.  The site owner will be able to see that the requests are coming from a Python script (unless you change the user agent), but one request every 10 or 20 minutes wouldn't bog down a server.  If you decide to chain requests, consider putting in a wait (like `time.sleep(5)`).  If the site doesn't allow you to send requests without a user-agent, that's a good indicator that they don't want scripts accessing it.

Comment: Read the  sites ToS and  look at the robots.txt if available then decide from there. Your question is unanswerable as it stands as only you know what site you are scraping.

Answer (score 1):

Although you don't want to do any harm, you can misconfigure the script by accident (we are just humans), generate suspicious activity and a real person might spend some time investigating your activity (I'm not kidding, these things really happen).

My suggestion is to use a testing service like https://httpbin.org/ to play with the requests library. HttpBin is actually created by the same person who started the requests library (Kenneth Reitz).